# Nginx - unwanted port redirect when error

Tags: redirect, nginx, iptables

Considering this configuration:

- Nginx listening on *:81
- iptables redirecting all traffic directed to :80 to Nginx at :81
- iptables blocking port :81 from the outside

Everything works well until some 404 takes place:

1. User going to `http://example.com:80/index.html` - everything works well. user -> server:80 -> Nginx:81
2. User clicks some not existing link, ie. `http://example.com:80/doesntExist.html` - user gets automatically redirected to `http://example.com:81/doesntExist.html`, which cannot be loaded because of iptables rule.

The question is: **how can I deter Nginx from redirecting to URL at port it thinks it's listening at?**

** EDIT: ** It seems like it's the problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/351212/nginx-redirects-to-port-8080-when-accessing-url-without-slash

**EDIT2: ** The solution provided in the first edit works - there were just some local cache related issues :)

Comment: nginx thinks port 81 is the correct port, which technically is correct. Why don't you have nginx listen on port 80?

Comment: @StevenV I know it is what Nginx thinks. I can't have it running on the target port - that's why I use `iptables` to redirect it. What's really compelling me, is why Nginx even does the redirection - after all it could just reply with 404 on that request directly, not with redirecting it to somewhere else and then 404ing.